# Numpy convolution: the range of m

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to do a discrete convolution like specified in the [documentation of numpy.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html):
[image: definition of discrete convolution operation]

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.random.rand(100)
array2 = np.random.rand(100)
conv = np.convolve(array1, array2, mode='same')
```

However, instead from -inf to +inf for m, I want m to be from 0 to n. (I.e., f and g are two arrays of the same length, and I want to walk through both of them while performing the convolution).

Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds equivalent to the given expression to me. Can you provide an example where the default behavior doesn't do what you want? (Include both actual and desired output.)

Comment: @user2357112 It seems to me that they are not equivalent for `n < len(array)`.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @askewchan: For terms with `m < 0`, the `f[m]` term is 0. For terms with `m > n`, the `g[n - m]` term is 0.

Comment: @user2357112, OK, `n` is not being used consistently.  Either it is the upper limit of the sum, or it is the index in the array.  I interpreted it as the the former only, you as the latter.

Comment: @askewchan: Looks like both to me. The output at position n is computed with a sum up to n.

Comment: @user2357112, yes that was my misunderstanding: I thought `n` was some constant limit that OP was introducing as the limit to the sum, hence my first comment.  Obviously `n < len(array)` is always true if `n` is the index to the array.

Comment: @user2357112 and askewchan, thanks a lot for your input! I realized that this is such a badly organized question due to my unclear understanding for what a convolution is... I am revising it. Will be done in an hour.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that I am mistakenly using the keyword "mode". It should be the following:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.random.rand(100)
array2 = np.random.rand(100)
conv = np.convolve(array1, array2, mode='full')[:100]
```